# converting ArrayList to Object array

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a List of type TicketBooking which i am setting to responseObject. when i try to get the list and convert back to TicketBooking type it is throwing `ClassCastException`. Here is my code

```
 List<TicketBooking> bookingDetailList = new ArrayList<TicketBooking>();
    bookingDetailList.add(booking);
    if(Utils.isNotNull(oldBooking)) 
        bookingDetailList.add(oldBooking);
    respObj.setObject(bookingDetailList);
```

from this method i  am returning respObj.

In the calling method

```
    List bookingList = new ArrayList();
    bookingList.add(Arrays.asList(respObj.getObject()));
    booking = (TicketBooking) bookingList.get(0);
```

throws `ClassCastException`

Please help.

Comment: what is full message and what is the type of `booking`

Comment: booking is of type TicketBooking and the message is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.abhibus.oprs.pojo.booking.TicketBooking

Comment: can I ask what the responseObject is? It seems like this is probably the cause of your issue. You need to cast it to the correct type when you call respObj.getObject()

Comment: it is object of class ResponseObject which has basic Object functionalities implemented in it

Comment: First you add a `List` to bookingList and on the next line you cast it to TicketBooking. No surprise here.

Comment: have you tried casting return type of respObj.getObject() to ArrayList<TicketBooking>..?..please check my updated code..

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a list of TicketBooking at the time of calling method.

your code

```
 List bookingList = new ArrayList();
 bookingList.add(Arrays.asList(respObj.getObject()));
 booking = (TicketBooking) bookingList.get(0);
```

should be replaced with

```
 List<TicketBooking> bookingList= new ArrayList<TicketBooking>();
 List list =  Arrays.asList(respObj.getObject());
 for(Object obj in list ){
    bookingList.add(obj);
    booking = bookingList.get(0);
 }
```

or following will do same

```
   List bookingList = new ArrayList();
bookingList.addAll(Arrays.asList(respObj.getObject()));
booking = (TicketBooking) bookingList.get(0);
```

Comment: you shouldnt need to cast it to TicketBooking since thats what it is. Maybe change your List bookingList to List<TicketBooking> bookingList. Then you dont need to cast bookingList.get(0) to a TicketBooking Object

Comment: it shows The method add(TicketBooking) in the type List<TicketBooking> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Object>. I tried this already, even i tried casting the array list to TicketBooking.

Comment: see the edit if you use .add you need to pass object from the list returned by respObj.getObject() if you use addAll you need to pass addAll(Arrays.asList(respObj.getObject()));

Comment: when i try this it says "The method add(TicketBooking) in the type List<TicketBooking> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)" so here itself i need to cast the object to TicketBooking. If i do that it is again throwing java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.abhibus.oprs.pojo.booking.TicketBooking

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.asList(respObj.getObject())
```

this expression is return a List object ,of course, throw ClassCasException

you should

```
List list =  Arrays.asList(respObj.getObject());
for(Object obj in list){
      bookingList.add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) with [`addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
List bookingList = new ArrayList();
bookingList.addAll(Arrays.asList(respObj.getObject()));
```

If you use add it will consider it as instance (which is of type `List`), and so the first element would be of type `List`  which you then trying to cast to `TicketBooking`

Answer (score 0):

```
List bookingList = new ArrayList();
bookingList.add(Arrays.asList(respObj.getObject()));//error is here
booking = (TicketBooking) bookingList.get(0);
```

I think in bookingList you added a whole List not a single TicketBooking object. and you are expecting a TicketBooking object.

**You should modify your code as follows.**

```
ArrayList<TicketBooking> bookingList= new ArrayList<TicketBooking>();
bookingList.addAll((ArrayList<TicketBooking>)respObj.getObject()); //Add all to add whole list
booking =  bookingList.get(0);
```

Comment: sorry ahmad, it is not working for me. the problem is it is arrayList and i'm trying to cast it to pojo class. It throws this error "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to com.abhibus.oprs.pojo.booking.TicketBooking"

Comment: that's what i emphasized ..have you tried addAll() method as i suggested..please tell us what respObj.getObject() returns exactly.

Comment: Please check the updated one.use code in the second block.I tried to cast to ArrayList<TicketBooking> whatever respObj.getObject() returns..